# DateTime AM/PM format convert to 24h format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i have a DateTime which is in AM/PM format . 
I want to convert it to 24h format , how can i do it?
thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The language is c# .NET .  I have a DB with DateTime Column and when i get it's values , they are in AM/PM format . I need it in 24h format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Date and times are not internally stored with any format in mind.

When you want to display the date/time, you use a format string on the `ToString` method of the object. There are [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format strings.

For 24 hours use:

```
string formatted24HourTime = myDateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: thank you.
I had a problem with getting the value from the DB but now it is ok, 
but if i want my datetime to be formated like 
YYYYMMDDHHmmss ? is there a format like this?

Comment: @olia - I linked to both the _standard_ and _custom_ documents on MSDN. I suggest looking there.

Answer (score 0):

> Date and times are not internally stored with any format in mind.

I hope so but ... I am not sure if ToString("HH") is the best solution.

I discovered following issue when developing a WP7 app: Some logic says that when current time/hour is between 22:00 to 07:00 DO "A" ELSE TO "B". Fine, simple logic.

I am using WP7 toolkit TimePicker control. When time is 10 PM (==22:00) and I am using the date.Hour given me by the TimePicker the hour is 10 and not 22 and so the logic went wrong.

OK, ToString("HH") is a workaround but I am not sure if it is a good solution. Should'n DateTime always using 24 hour format and only for displaying using AM/PM ...?

Or do I missing something?